Is the sum of residuals is zero when the intercept is known (not fitted)
The sum of residuals is zero in simple linear regression, when there is an intercept. However, what if there is a true non-zero intercept that is already known?

Have you worked out a simple example?  For instance, suppose you observe values of $y=1$ and $y=2$ from a distribution with known mean $0.$  What is the sum of the residuals?

I mentioned that the true intercept is known but not zero, but this is a good idea

The specific value of the intercept is immaterial.

I think the specific value might matter if there's a way to prove this. In the proof for OLS that the residuals are zero, the fact that the intercept is non-zero is important.

That the value of the intercept is irrelevant becomes plain when you think of it as merely setting the origin of the units of measurement.

Let's simulate an example.
set.seed(2024)

# Deine the intercept in position 1 and slope in position 2
#
B <- c(7, 1)

# Set a sample size
#
N <- 10

# Define the values of a feature
#
x <- seq(1, N, 1)

# Simulate the error term
#
e <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)

# Calculate the conditional expected values
#
Ey <- cbind(1, x) %*% B

# Add the errors to the conditional expected values
#
y <- Ey + e

# Subtract out the known intercept before fitting a model that has the
# intercept fixed at 0. This is part of an R trick to force a particular
# value of the intercept
#
y_fitted <- y - B[1]#
L <- lm(y_fitted ~ 0 + x)

# Make predictions based on the model, adding back the known intercept.
# This is equivalent to fitting the original model with the known intercept
#
preds <- predict(L) + B[1]

# Calculate the sum of the residuals
#
sum((y - preds))

This sum is 2.387752, far larger than is reasonably explained by floating point arithmetic on a computer. Thus, it seems that the sum of the residuals being zero depends on the intercept being fitted, not known. A formal proof of this could get into the fun of working this out through the matrix algebra.

Thank you! I would be very interested in a formal proof

Such a proof has appeared many, many times here on CV.
